# How to modify attributes of an existing object with the HDF5 lib?

Tags: c++, attributes, hdf5

I am trying to build an C++ application that utilizes the HDF5 library. For my usecase, I have an initialization phase in which I create the structure (groups, attributes) for the file and give them a default value. Later on, I am trying to come back to the attributes and modify them. My current attempt is found below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

const H5std_string FILE_NAME( "test.h5" );

int main (void)
{
  /*
   * Create a new file. If file exists its contents will be overwritten.
   */
  H5::H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

  /*
   * Create Groups and Attributes
   */
  H5::Group g_data(file.createGroup( "/Data" ));
  H5::DataSpace dspace = H5::DataSpace(H5S_SCALAR);
  H5::Attribute version = g_data.createAttribute("version", H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT, dspace);
  int curVersion = {1};
  version.write(H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT, &curVersion);
  version.close();
  dspace.close();
  g_data.close();

  // WORK WITH DATASETS

  H5::Attribute new_version = file.openAttribute("/Data/version");
  int newVersion = {2};
  new_version.write(H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT, &newVersion);
  new_version.close();

  file.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I do, however, get an error when executing this:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.0-patch1) thread 140574792701760:
  #000: ../../../src/H5A.c line 438 in H5Aopen(): unable to load attribute info from object header for attribute: '/Data/version'
    major: Attribute
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #001: ../../../src/H5Oattribute.c line 530 in H5O_attr_open_by_name(): can't locate attribute: '/Data/version'
    major: Attribute
    minor: Object not found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'H5::AttributeIException'
```

It is probably due to the fact that I cannot use absolute paths from the file root to access attributes. The groups objects have already been closed at the time of the modification, yet I want to access their attributes.

Does anybody know how this is done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to solve the issue with the HDF5 library you are using but with [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) in C++ it can be done as follows:

```
// create HDF5 file 'test.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
HDFql::execute("create and use file test.h5");

// create group 'Data'
HDFql::execute("create group Data");

// create attribute 'version' (in group 'Data') of data type int with an initial value of '1'
HDFql::execute("create attribute Data/version as int values(1)");

// insert (i.e. write) value '2' into attribute 'version'
HDFql::execute("insert into Data/version values(2)");
```

Additional info can be found in HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) as well as [examples](http://www.hdfql.com/examples) that illustrate how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely look into that and try to use the HDFql lib. I will not yet close the question, just in case somebody has solved this problem with the HDF5 lib.